# Fixing type mismatch error 13 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am new to coding and am trying to develop a userform that allows me to populate a database.

I am trying to set up some validation for the data that can be input to the database through the userform.

The code I am using for this is shown below where Reg is the name of the controls on my userform.

When I run this part of the code it stops on the first line and shows the Type Mismatch Error 13 message box.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated.

```
Sub ValidCombo1()

    If Reg18.Value = "" And ((Reg17.Value <> "1" Or (Reg15.Value <> "0" Or "") Or Reg16.Value <> "A" Or Reg19.Value <> "") Or (Reg17.Value <> "" And Reg15.Value <> "" And Reg16.Value <> "" And Reg19.Value <> "")) Then

        MsgBox "Invalid Foundations combination"

        Reg13.Value = ""

    ElseIf Reg25.Value = "" And ((Reg24.Value <> "1" Or (Reg22.Value <> "0" Or "") Or Reg23.Value <> "A" Or Reg26.Value <> "") Or (Reg24.Value <> "" And Reg22.Value <> "" And Reg23.Value <> "" And Reg26.Value <> "")) Then

        MsgBox "Invalid Inverts and Aprons combination"

        Reg13.Value = ""
```

Comment: can you put the if statement into a code block please?

Answer (score 2):

Your code might have other issues, but expressions like

```
Reg15.Value <> "0" Or ""
```

are a type mismatch. `""` is a string, not a Boolean value.

Replacing `Reg15.Value <> "0" Or ""` by

```
Reg15.Value <> "0" And Reg15.Value <> ""
```

(which I think is your intention) will eliminate those type mismatches.